# Define custom window functions in pySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, window-functions

I have a dataframe in Spark for which I would like to create a column defined recursively like that:

```
new_column_row = f(last_column_row, other_parameters)
```

The best way to do that would be to define my custom window function, but I cannot find a way to do it in PySpark, anybody encountered the same problem ?

### The case I am working on is:

My problem is about reconstructing an order book from a list of orders:

I have a dataframe like that (value is what I would like to calculate)

```
size | price | output 
1    |  1    | {1:1}
1.2  |  1.1  | {1:1, 1.2:1.1}
1.3  |  - 1. | {1.2:1.1}
```

Output is updated at each row like that (in python pseudocode)

```
- if price not in Output: 
     Output[price] = size
- if price in Output: 
     Output[price] = output[price] + size
     if Output[price] = 0: 
          del Output[price]
```

Comment: dont you have enough to play with partionBy, orderBy, rangeBetween and rowBetween ?

Comment: Nope,  I really need to define my own window function to achieve my goal.

Comment: It is not the range of my window functions which is problematic but the fact that the simple window function  (`last`, `last_value`, `avg`, ...) will not work for what I want and I would like to be able to define my own window function instead

Comment: I am curious to discover a use-case that the classic analytic functions [cannot solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) !

Comment: @Steven I edited my question with a description of the case I am working on

Comment: @Steven does it sound clearer to you?